# Wodpress: Change ###ADMIN_EMAIL### only for all notification email

Tags: wordpress, hook, wp-mail

Is there a way to change ### ADMIN_EMAIL ### for all automatic notifications email in wordpress?

For example in change password notification and change email for user, I would like a custom email different form real admin email

> If you did not change your email, please contact the Site Administrator at **###ADMIN_EMAIL###**

> If you did not change your email, please contact the Site Administrator at **###CUSTOM_EMAIL###**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filters:

- `password_change_email` ([source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/password_change_email/))
- `email_change_email` ([source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/email_change_email/))

and update the admin email address using `str_replace()`.

Each of the above filters accepts 3 parameters (arrays):

- `$email_change_email` or `$pass_change_email` (depending on filter used)
- `$user`
- `$userdata`

The first parameter has an array item called `message` which holds some strings which are dynamically replaced:

- `###USERNAME###` The current user's username.
- `###ADMIN_EMAIL###` The admin email in case this was unexpected.
- `###EMAIL###` The user's email address.
- `###SITENAME###` The name of the site.
- `###SITEURL###` The URL to the site.

**Complete code:**

Change `other_email@your-domain.com` to your new admin email address.

```php
/**
 * Change admin email in notifications.
 *
 * This applies to password and email change notifications.
 *
 * @param (array) $pass_change_email Used to build wp_mail().
 * @param (array) The original user array.
 * @param (array) The updated user array.
 *
 * @return (array) $pass_change_email Updated wp_mail() content.
 */
add_filter('password_change_email', 'replace_admin_email_in_notification_emails', 10, 3);
add_filter('email_change_email', 'replace_admin_email_in_notification_emails', 10, 3);

function replace_admin_email_in_notification_emails( $pass_change_email, $user, $userdata ) {
  $pass_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###ADMIN_EMAIL###', 'other_email@your-domain.com', $pass_change_email['message'] );

  return $pass_change_email;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer is somewhat lacking. If someone read your post and didn't click on links... Would they know what to do? [answer]

Comment: @HowardE I agree, I updated the answer with more details.